# JavaScript plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

у меня countup jquery плагин есть все сделал.Открываю файл html просто с компютера все работает как только с FTP на сайте не открывается счетчик код:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">

    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }    
        #box1{
            height: 200vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(i1.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            display: table;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        #box2{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(i2.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            display: table;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        #box3{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(i3.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            display: table;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        h1{
            font-family: arial black;
            font-size: 50px;
            color:white;
            margin: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;

        }
        .hfirst{
-webkit-animation-duration:0.5s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;


}

    </style>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="countUp.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box1">
        <center>    <h1 class="hfirst animated zoomIn">FireSafety</h1></center>
    <div style="text-align:center;height:100px;">
<center><div class="counter animated slideInDown"><h1 id="counter" style="color: white;padding-top: 25px;"></h1></div></center>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
  useEasing : true, 
  useGrouping : true, 
  separator : ',', 
  decimal : '.', 
  prefix : '', 
  suffix : '' 
};
var demo = new CountUp("counter", 0, 413200, 0, 10, options);
demo.start();
</script>
]
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
            <h1 >FireSafety</h1>

        </div>
        <div id="box3">
            <h1>FireSafety</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: лежат ли на вашем FTP необходимые файлы по необходимым путям?

Comment: Если пользуетесь хромом, то нажмите F12. В правом верхнем углу открывшегося окна, скорее всего, увидите крест в красном круге. Кликните по нему и узнаете, почему счётчик не работает.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token такая ошибка и вопрос не понял необходимые файлы какие и какие пути